# Is it true that D A D F A D is the bluesiest guitar tuning?

Tags: guitar

Is D A D F A D the bluesiest guitar tuning ?   If not, what tuning is ?

Comment: There can be no such thing as a 'bluesiest guitar tuning'. Vtc.

Comment: True, but that in itself is an answer, “bluesy” comes from the playing, not the tuning.

Answer (score 2):

A tuning on its own isn’t bluesy or not bluesy. It is just a series of notes a guitar can be tuned to. In your case it is tuned to a D minor chord. It is not more or less bluesy than say, a D major tuning or standard tuning. What is or isn’t bluesy is the way the instrument is played regardless of the tuning.